# Error when compiling Tweak made with THEOS

Tags: cydia, tweak, theos

Here is my Tweak.xm:

```
%hook Blockhead

-(float)health {
return 1;
}

%end
```

but i always get this error when I try to compile it:

```
make: xcode-select: Command not found
/var/mobile/myTweak/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin/iphone.mk.21:
*** first argument to `word' function must be greater than 0. Stop.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Both of the answers are wrong. The problem is that you don't have the SDKs. http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

I compiled this part of code as it is and it compiled fine with no warnings.
It looks like a problem in include.substrate.h was this meant to be include/substrate.h?

If you are adding the substrate header, in my version this is not needed as it is automatically added, try without.

Comment: I didn't #include anything in my file. What device are you using?

I'm getting a different error now:

make: xcode-select: Command not found
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin/iphone.mk.21: ***first argument to `word' function must be greater than 0. Stop

Comment: I'm using an iphone 5s and a 4s. It sounds like you may have a theos problem, try re-installing it. There are a few different branches out there, i use the version from the creators of theos.

Answer (score 0):

**it has to be:**

```
%hook Blockhead

-(float)health {
return 1.0f;
}

%end
```

**:D
FuroowHD**